# How can I show full text, not summary for the homepage and in categories?

Tags: themes

I'm using the 'de.pinque' wordpress theme and it doesnt have an option to show full text in the homepage.

This is my site (test site) with the theme and you can see its showing a summary of text on the homepage
http://test99.info/

I also would like to be able to get full text when I click on the categories in the navigation bar. 
As you can see here, when I click on the 'A' category it also shows an excerpts of the the article instead of the full text

So how can i get the full text on both these. Below are my index.php, function.php, header.php, and category.php if you need to see them. Thanks

edit: im having trouble pasting the codes, it says i can't post more than 2 links please help

Answer (score 3):

replace `the_excerpt();` with `the_content();` in index.php and category.php ,done.